# Xamarin.Android Application Connecting to SQL Database

Tags: android, sql, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am looking to create a simple xamarin.android mobile application which can connect to and interact with an SQL database hosted in azure. What would be the best way to create this connection? I have been able to create a simple console application which can do this if that helps, but am unable to do a similar thing with an android app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Azure App Service Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started/) to work with an SQL database hosted in Azure in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these [samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/#Samples) from Xamarin. The "MyShoope" App in particular uses [data storage](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyShoppe#my-shoppe-setup).

> I have provided my existing .NET Backend for reference on how to create your controllers and data entities to publish to Azure. Read through the Azure Mobile Apps tutorial to learn how to create and setup your own Mobile Apps backend for My Shoppe.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/